# Can two components have the exact same state, asynchronously updating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, react-redux, react-functional-component

**Context:**

I am working on a React App, and have two sibling components *(**NOTE**: there is no parent-child component relationship)* which both have one identical state. They need to asynchronously update (i.e. When Component1 causes the state to change, then Component2 should have knowledge of that state change and use the changed state as the initial state).

**The Problem:**

I am using useState(intitialValue) to set the states in each Component, but I am noticing that this is causing my states to go out of sync, as the state depends on modifications done by Component1 or Component2.

(i.e.)

If Component1 caused the state to change from "red" to "green" via some component method, and in Component2 I do:

```
useState("red")
```

Then Component2 did not correctly get the information of "green" that was from Component1; instead it received the information of "red" from the initialization of the initial state.

PS:
*Please don't* simply tell me to pass the state as props. Reminder these are NOT parent-child components!

***Any help is greatly appreciated. I think this is a great and common ReactJS issue to solve.***

Comment: Take a look at using a context provider to share the state

Comment: Thanks a ton! Just googled it and this looks like this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @VigneshPethuraj what you describe is the use case for [recoiljs](https://recoiljs.org/). Check both the Context API and recoiljs and pick one of them

Answer (score 0):

If there is no any relation between two separated components, why they should be synchronous? the substantial question is that, what event do you expect cause to change state in both component? then you can subscribe both components to that event. event can be router change, received data from server asynchronously, browser based events (like resize) or common data changing in memory. some of these events have own hook like route change. But if your event is data change you can use a common service in the both like [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/),  [rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) or some other state management frameworks. Or if you are pro can write your own hook for your particular event.

*If you had shared some sample code, it would help more.*